# How to mass delete brackets and their contents in txt files?

Tags: regex, dataframe, notepad++, txt

I have 1000~ txt files that contain data inside curly {} brackets. example:

```
A = {
 bananas = 5
 apples = 1
}
B = {
 oranges = 5
 bananas = 3
   BA = {
      apples = 19
   }
 cookies = 2
}
C = {
 bananas = 19
}
```

Now how exactly would i delete all lines from B = { to the } that closes the brackets? The biggest problem i have is the fact that the B brackets can sometimes contain more brackets... Feel free to suggest any program, only requirements being that its free and simple enough to use for a moron like me. Note that the BA in the example is completely random. Only B is constant.
what i would want:

```
A = {
 bananas = 5
 apples = 1
}
C = {
 bananas = 19
}
```

Ive tried notepad++.

Answer (score 0):

Open only the documents you want to modify
CTRL+H (replace)
Find what:`(.*\r\n)(B = {.*}\r\n)(.*)`
Replace with:`$1$3`
check . matches new line
Click Replace All in All Opened Documents
Verify results before saving

helpful information:  https://superuser.com/questions/481276/how-to-make-regex-match-across-multiple-lines-in-notepad

Notepad++, so... Windows?

You can also do this in PowerShell.  Here's a brute force method using a loop.  This may be more elegant using a regular expression.

This locates the beginning of the block (B = {) then counts the curly braces until we're back to zero.  One thing you may consider:  Could a name or value contain a curly brace?  That would throw off the count.  You would need to modify this to account for that case.

```
foreach ($i in Get-ChildItem) {
    $s = Get-Content $i | Out-String
    $i = $s.IndexOf('B = {')
    $depth = 0

    for ($j = $i + 5; $depth -ge 0; $j++) {
        if ($s[$j] -eq '{') {
            $depth++
        }
        elseif ($s[$j] -eq '}') {
            $depth--
        }
    }
    $s.Substring(0, $i - 2) + $s.Substring($j)
}
```